# Can't unmarhal to Java Map when elements are in a namespace

Tags: jaxb, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to use JAXB to unmarshal some XML into a Java Map.

I believe I'm using the JAXB reference implementation provided by Sun/Oracle (com.sun.xml.internal.bind...

Here's an (abbreviated) portion of relevant XML from the instance file:

```
<Report 
    xmlns="http://www.escholar.com/eReports" 
    path="Books" reportName="BooksRead" eTag="eTag value">

    <SelectList>
        <entry>
           <key>DOC</key>
           <value>Microsoft Word (DOC)</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
           <key>PDF</key>
           <value>Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF)</value>
        </entry>
    </Selectlist>
.
.
.
</Report>
```

As you can see, all the elements are in a namespace.

Here's the annotated Java field for selectList:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "InputSelectionType", namespace=ReportJAXB.NAMESPACE, propOrder = {
"selectList"
})

public class InputSelectionTypeJAXB extends InputParameterTypeJAXB 
                                    implements InputSelectionType
    {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="SelectList", namespace=ReportJAXB.NAMESPACE)
    protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> selectList;
```

Here's the definition of ReportJAXB.NAMESPACE (same as in instance file @xmlns):

```
    protected final static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.escholar.com/eReports";
```

Everything in application is working fine with regard to unmarhsaling except that the selectList map ends up having no elements.

It's also worth mentioning that this all worked fine until I added namespaces.

I'm guessing that the problem has to do with the **entry**, **key** and **value** tags.  These are not tag names I chose.  These are the tag names that JAXB seems to assume when unmarhsaling to a Java Map.  I discovered them by examining marshaled output before I introduced namespaces.

So my best guess is that the reason this is not working because thosse tags are in the namespace in the instance file, but the namespace I provide in the @XmlElementWrapper annotation isn't inherited by those implied tags.

If this were some other Collection (like a list) you can annotate the immediate children of the grouping list element with an @XmlElement.  But Maps have these implied substructures/sub-elements.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations treat `java.util.Map` as a type of domain object (like `Customer`, `Address`, etc) instead of a collection class (like `java.util.List`).  This means it only creates one mapping for it.  As such it does not inherit the namespace qualification from your domain model and is not namespace qualified.  If you create an instance of your model and marshal it out you will get a sense of what this means.

If you want the XML representation of the `Map` to be namespace qualified then you can leverage an `XmlAdapter` to do this.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html